# ektorp / CouchDB update / synchronize folder

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

In jcouchdb there is an util class org.jcouchdb.util.CouchDBUpdater that allows to update documents from your local file system into CouchDB (used for example for copying design documents into CouchDB). Is there anything similar in ektorp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Embed your design document in your repository class by using @View, @GenerateView, @Filter, @ShowFuction, @ListFuction annotations. The corresponding design doc will automatically be updated at application upstart. See http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d100e753
2. Implement a org.ektorp.dataload.DataLoader which allow you to bootstrap your DB with any kind of documents. See http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d100e1170

Comment: Actually I was trying to avoid first option since most of the design documents that I'd like to load are manually generated.

Comment: About the second, and as far as I can see, the difference is that DefaultDataLoader loads from one single document that contains all JSON documents while CouchDBUpdater uploads from file system (getting the identifiers from the file path).